# Open the Door and Sleep Forever

Tags: mathematics, word, enigmatic-puzzle, symbols

[image: Open the Door and Sleep Forever]

Clues: 
_ _ _ [plank of wood]
_ _ _ [musical note]
_ _ _ [rock]

34575  92200  172875  149825  172875  138300  242025  161350  80675  149825
[line]
11525

---

Instructions: Name That Landmark

_ _ _ _ T _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The landmark is

> MOUNT EVEREST!

Explanation:
On the left side we have three images which

> can be preceded with the word 'key' (keyboard, keynote, keystone).
>  Converting 'key' to A1Z26, we get 11525, which flows along the arrow to the left:
>  [image: key]

On the right side we now have several large numbers

> listed over a bar and '11525'. This looks like a division bar; we can divide each number by 11525 to get:
>  3, 9, 15, 13, 15, 12, 21, 14, 7, 13, 1

> Converting back to letters using A1Z26, this spells "Chomolunga", which is the original name for "[Mount Everest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest)".  MOUNT EVEREST fits in the bottom blanks, and is the final answer.

Regarding the title, Stiv found:

> open the door = KEY, sleep forever = EVER-REST)

Comment: I think the title can be explained by rot13(bcra gur qbbe = XRL, fyrrc sberire = RIRE-ERFG)